# Android/Swift JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError System.loadLibrary looking in the wrong path

Tags: java, android, linker, java-native-interface, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to load two libraries via JNI:

1. A self-contained Swift library that interacts with its own Swift code
2. A C library that predominantly interacts with other C code, except for one call to to the Swift library, above.

When I call System.loadLibrary on the Swift library and all its dependencies, they all load fine. As soon as I run `System.loadLibrary("LocalCLibrary")` – whether it's after loading the others, or not running loadLibrary on the others at all – the app crashes when trying to resolve the internal dependency to the Swift library. The crash stacktrace sends a very confusing message:

```
dlopen failed: library "/Users/ephemer/AndroidTest/app/src/main/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libSwiftTest.so" not found
```

The reason I'm so confused (and frustrated..) is that this path is clearly on my local development machine and not on the Android device. So I'm thinking I must be linking the two libraries incorrectly.

---

This is how I'm currently linking the libraries.. my Android.mk looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

### A bunch of dependencies omitted here ###

# The Swift library:

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE := SwiftTest
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libSwiftTest.so
    include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


# The local C(++) library:

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE := LocalCLibrary
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
        file1.cpp \
        $(ANOTHER_PATH)/file2.cpp

    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(ANOTHER_PATH)
    LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lSystem -lLibraries -lHere
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := localDependency
    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := SwiftTest
    LOCAL_CFLAGS = -O3
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And the C++ code looks like this (simplified of course):

```
void Java_com_test_androidtest_MainActivity_nativeFunc(JNIEnv *env, jobject self) {
    // Do stuff here that depends on other C library code...
    SwiftLibrary_callback(param1, param2); // do more processing
}
```

The C++ header also includes the Swift Library's header, which defines

```
extern void SwiftLibrary_callback(type param1, type param2);
```

---

I wonder whether the linking problem would go away if I could somehow remove the library dependency at link time and somehow let it find the correct symbols on load: The Swift library actually loads fine by itself, it's only when the library that depends on it tries to load that everything breaks.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: How we fixed this: https://medium.com/@ephemer/how-we-put-an-app-in-the-android-play-store-using-swift-67bd99573e3c